# How to embed ODP.NET Oracle Data Client with Windows Setup

Tags: c#, odp.net, setup-deployment, system.data.oracleclient

Is there anyway to embed System.Data.OracleClient on Client Machine after running setup? I tried to add file after signing it yet gives error:

> System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version
>   8.1.7 or greater

It is not practical to install ODP.NET on client machine separately. I selected RegisterType as

> vsdraCOM

Comment: What do you mean by embedding the dll ? you want to GAC it ? or simply package it with the MSI which is to be installed in the application folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices outside of installing the full oracle client:

- Use the new managed provider
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=I1q50HnUh_w
- Use the "xcopy" installation which can be installed with a batch file.
  http://www.brothersincode.com/post/Oracle-ODPnet-xcopy-deployment-for-aspnet.aspx